# Trying to create sliding toggle submenu in JQuery

Tags: jquery, menu, slidetoggle, sliding

I'm trying to create a sliding submenu using JQuery toggle. I've tried the following but to no avail:

`<script>
    $(".menu li a").click(function(){
    var ul = $(this).children("ul");
    if (ul.is(":none")) {
        ul.slideDown();
    } else {
        ul.slideUp();
    }
    });
    </script>`

and also

`<script>
    $("ul li.menu-item a").click(function() {
    $(this).children("ul").toggle();
    });
    </script>`

The HTML code it applies to is:

```
<div class="menu-brk-products-container">
<ul id="menu-brk-products" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-65"><a>Smoke Alarms – Ionisation</a>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li id="menu-item-432" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-432"><a href="/?portfolio_cats=battery-powered-smoke-alarms">Battery Powered Alarms</a>
           </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

click binding must be done after document loading:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("ul li.menu-item a").click(function() { $(this).children("ul").toggle(); });
});
```

also, this click is bound to **a** element and since it doesn't contain any **ul** it won't do anything.
If you want to make "Battery Powered Alarms" toggle on "Smoke alarms ..." click then remove a from selector (but it will make "Battery Powered Alarms" dissapear on click also, you need different selector).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div class="menu-brk-products-container">
    <ul id="menu-brk-products" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-65"><a>Smoke Alarms – Ionisation</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none">
                <li id="menu-item-432" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-432"><a href="/?portfolio_cats=battery-powered-smoke-alarms">Battery Powered Alarms</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu li a").click(function(){ 
        var ul = $(this).parent().children("ul"); 

        if (ul.is(":hidden")) { 
            ul.slideDown(); 
        } 
        else { 
            ul.slideUp(); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The biggest issue was getting the children. "this" was the anchor tag, not the <li> element, thus no matches were coming back. Also I changed the test to ":hidden" for if we should slide up or down.